# Create collage from many images

Tags: windows-7, photoshop

I'm looking for a straightforward and easy way to make an collage/image grid from a bunch of `.jpg` files, they're roughly the same size (but not exactly). Basically I want to make an album art wallpaper from all the `folder.jpg` files I have. Just like the Mac OS itunes album art screensaver. Eg:

[image]

I have PhotoShop, and have read this [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-huge-printable-poster-from-your-iTunes-albu/) guide, but I feel that it's a lot of manual effort to have to resize all the images perfectly etc. I also realise PhotoShop makes everything possible, but at the cost of my time...

Comment: What is your question? Please update your post with an actual question. This looks more like an overview of what you have done thus far rather than a question that needs an answer.

Comment: @RichardChambers I'd read that as "I want a tool that can do that without the complications from that guide" – i.e. a tool that takes all those images and creates a collage. Details are of course missing, like what parameters KERR wants to pass: final size, matrix …(e.g. 4x10 like in the picture)? Very similar to what is [described here for ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16249) I guess. Would that meet your rrequirements, KERR?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question now. @Izzy - I will try out that method, cheers!